# $http.post to php file, 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I am tryng to send some JSON data to PHP file but I get 500 internal server error.

The javascript function to post data:

```
 $scope.addcommentaire = function() {
 var onecomment= {page:document.getElementById('hiddenpage').value, text:this.textMessage,author:this.auteur };    

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'data/comment.php',
                data: onecomment,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {                        
                        $scope.commentaires.unshift(onecomment);                       
                })                 
           };
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('data/comment.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString,true);

 array_push( array('page' => 'essai', 'text' => 'essai2', 'author' => 'vince'));

  $jsonData = json_encode($data);
  file_put_contents('data/comment.json', $jsonData);

 print_r($jsonData);
```

?>

And the error on the console:

```
     POST http://webtoutsaint.com/data/comment.php 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.js:8707
(anonymous function) angular.js:8707
sendReq angular.js:8501
$http.serverRequest angular.js:8221
wrappedCallback angular.js:11682
wrappedCallback angular.js:11682
(anonymous function) angular.js:11786
Scope.$eval angular.js:12946
Scope.$digest angular.js:12756
Scope.$apply angular.js:13050
(anonymous function) angular.js:20573
eventHandler
```

The htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.webtoutsaint.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://webtoutsaint.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### If not already activated, activates the RewriteEngine module
RewriteEngine On

### If using a .htaccess file, uncomment the following line
Options +FollowSymLinks

### If the Host header is not correctly set
###RequestHeader set Host "api.seo4ajax.com"

### If a bot requests an escaped URL then proxify the request to SEO4Ajax
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  _escaped_fragment_=  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://api.seo4ajax.com/5cdad99ad52efb8560de760adf13d862/$1 [P,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* index.html  [L]
```

Does someone know what occurs the error?

Comment: drop `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` into the php to find out what the error is

Comment: What http deamon are you using? What does this http deamon report in their error log?

Comment: it's PHP 5.5, I don't know about the log. It is a regular server on OVH (not VPS)..

Comment: @andrew The error_reporting is not working, because I don't get access to the PHP file. And the function which call the page is only in HTML and Javascript

Comment: 500 errors are to my expierence something in the `.htaccess`

Comment: @vincentT Something must map the url's to a script or page on your server. Apache is a common http deamon. Lighttpd, IIS and nginx are other http deamons. Internal server errors can be generated by a http deamon due to bad or invalid configuration. Find out what http deamon your server uses.

Comment: sorry, yes it is Apache @Sumurai8

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: But I've deleted the htaccess file to try, and the error is the same

Comment: @Martijn yes maybe, but if I delete it, it should work then ?

Comment: Can you access the Apache error log or does your hosting provider save a error file in your own directory?

Answer (score 1):

with the javascript you posted, the data can be retrieved at the server end with:

```
$_POST['page'];
$_POST['text'];
$_POST['author'];
```

Unless there is additional code that you have not posted

```
file_get_contents('data/comment.json'); 
$data = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```

will produce errors if:

1) `data/comment.json` cannot be located on the server file system.

2) `data/comment.json` does not contain valid json data.

Also:

```
array_push( array('page' => 'essai', 'text' => 'essai2', 'author' => 'vince'));
```

will produce errors as  two parameters are expected: [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Yes but all this problems are may be true, but I would like to know if I have access to the PHP file first..

Comment: To check if file exists use is_file() http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php